# How to remove any utf8mb4 characters in string

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, utf8mb4

Using C# how can utf8mb4 characters (emoji, etc.) be removed from a string, so that the result is full utf8 compliant.

Most of the solutions involve changing the database configuration, but unfortunately I don't have that possibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should replace surrogate characters with a `replacementCharacter` (that could even be `string.Empty`)

This is a MySql problem, given the `utf8mb4`. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) there is the difference between utf8 and utf8mb4 in MySql. The difference is that utf8 doesn't support 4 byte utf8 sequences. By looking at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), 4 byte utf8 sequences are those > 0xFFFF, so that in utf16 require two `char` (that are named surrogate pairs). This method remove surrogate pairs characters. When found "coupled" (a high + a low surrogate pair), then a single `replacementCharacter` is substituted, otherwise a orphan (wrong) high or a low surrogate pair is replaced by a `replacementCharacte`.

```
public static string RemoveSurrogatePairs(string str, string replacementCharacter = "?")
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char ch = str[i];

        if (char.IsSurrogate(ch))
        {
            if (sb == null)
            {
                sb = new StringBuilder(str, 0, i, str.Length);
            }

            sb.Append(replacementCharacter);

            // If there is a high+low surrogate, skip the low surrogate
            if (i + 1 < str.Length && char.IsHighSurrogate(ch) && char.IsLowSurrogate(str[i + 1]))
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        else if (sb != null)
        {
            sb.Append(ch);
        }
    }

    return sb == null ? str : sb.ToString();
}
```